# How to get only a particular character from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a date string which looks like:

> Feb 21 (Tue) 11:30 -  13:30

I want to change the output to

> 02/21/2012...

I tried to save a few of the words like 'Mon', 'Tue', etc in an array and replace them with "". But its not working and I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Please help me.

Comment: Unless you assume 2012 there's no way to get the year effectively from that string.

Comment: I need help in converting "Feb 21 (Tue) 11:30 - 13:30" to 21/02...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var str="Feb 21 (Tue) 11:30 - 13:30";

return str.subStr(4,2) + "/" + convertToNum(str.subStr(0,3)) + "/2012";

function convertToNum(monthName) {
  ... convert month name to number ...
}
```

Notice that Year was not given in the string above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This will remove the time from the string and will parse the resulting date into a date object:

```
var date = "Feb 21 (Tue) 11:30 - 13:30";
var newdate = date.replace(/ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g, "");

var d = Date.parse(newdate);

var mydate = new Date(d);
document.write(mydate.getDate()+"/"+(mydate.getMonth()+1));
```

The end line shows how to get it in the format `dd/mm`. (Note in javascript date format months start from 0, not 1. i.e. January is 0, February is 1 - don't ask, I don't know! lol... just remember to +1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use string manipulation like this:

```
function formatDateString(input){
    var m = /^(\w{3})\s(\d+).*$/.exec(input);
    return ({"Jan":"01","Feb":"02","Mar":"03","Apr":"04","May":"05","Jun":"06","Jul":"07","Aug":"08","Sep":"09","Oct":"10","Nov":"11","Dec":"12"})[m[1]] + "/" + m[2] + "/" + (new Date().getFullYear());
}
```

Or you could reformat the string and use the Date object to parse it.

```
function formatDateString(input){
    var a = new Date(input.substr(0, 6) + " " + new Date().getFullYear());
    return ("0" + (a.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + a.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + a.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert(datestr, year){
    var split1 = datestr.split("(");
    var split2 = split1[1].split(")");
    var fulldate  = new Date(split1[0] + year);
    var date = fulldate.getDate();
    var month = fulldate.getMonth();
    return ((date < 10)?"0"+date:date) + "/" + ((month < 10)?"0"+month:month) +  split2[1];
}

var datestr = "Feb 21 (Tue) 11:30 - 13:30";
convert(datestr, 2012);
```